# CakePHP 1.3 clear cache for single view

Tags: cakephp, caching, view

In controller I can use `clearCache();` but it deletes whole /cache/views/ directory. Is there any way to delete only the current pageid cache?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the docblock / documentation on it

```
function clearCache($params = null, $type = 'views', $ext = '.php') {}
```

it states for $params:

```
@param string|array $params As String name to be searched for deletion, if name is a directory all files in
 *   directory will be deleted. If array, names to be searched for deletion. If clearCache() without params,
 *   all files in app/tmp/cache/views will be deleted
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. 
I don't know why I couldn't find this.

Comment: The code is open source :) https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/basics.php#L451